# SQL Server 2014 one to many issue

Tags: sql-server, one-to-many

I have 2 tables, Orders and AWB

once paid, orders becomes invoice and an AWB is generated for shipment

In Orders I have a Flag 'HOLD' on each record

Orders are often 1 single Item, therefore 1 Record, but sometimes there are Orders with more rows

I want that when it happen, and at least one order is hold, the full shipment is blocked
but as you can see from this SQLFiddle, my `solution` requires that all 3 orders lines are on Hold to stop the AWB

how can I achieve what I need?

Update.. sqlFiddle does not work properly: here the Example

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  OrderID varchar(10) NULL,
  UserID nvarchar(20) NULL,
  ItemID nvarchar(20) NULL,
  Quantity int NULL,
  Hold bit NULL
)

CREATE TABLE AWB (
  ShipmentID varchar(10) NULL,
  OrderID varchar(10) NULL,
  UserID nvarchar(20) NULL,
  Content nvarchar(200) NULL,
  TrackingID nvarchar(20) NULL
)



Insert into Orders (OrderID,UserID,ItemID,Quantity,Hold) 
   VALUES ('25', 'John', 'Item2',1,0)
Insert into Orders (OrderID,UserID,ItemID,Quantity,Hold) 
   VALUES ('26', 'Frank', 'Item3',1,0)
Insert into Orders (OrderID,UserID,ItemID,Quantity,Hold) 
   VALUES ('25', 'John', 'Item3',2,0)
Insert into Orders (OrderID,UserID,ItemID,Quantity,Hold) 
   VALUES ('25', 'John', 'Item4',1,1)
Insert into Orders (OrderID,UserID,ItemID,Quantity,Hold) 
   VALUES ('27', 'Bill', 'Item1',2,0)
Insert into Orders (OrderID,UserID,ItemID,Quantity,Hold) 
   VALUES ('28', 'Anna', 'Item3',4,0)


Insert into AWB (ShipmentID,ORderID,UserID,Content,TrackingID) 
  VALUES ('A414', '26', 'Frank', '1xItem3', 'DHL232455')
Insert into AWB (ShipmentID,ORderID,UserID,Content,TrackingID) 
   VALUES ('A415', '25', 'John', '4xItem1,1xItem2,2xItem3,1xItem4', 'DHL232465')
Insert into AWB (ShipmentID,ORderID,UserID,Content,TrackingID) 
   VALUES ('A416', '26', 'Bill', '2xItem1', 'DHL232467')
Insert into AWB (ShipmentID,ORderID,UserID,Content,TrackingID) 
  VALUES ('A417', '26', 'Anna', '4xItem3', 'DHL232489')




SELECT DISTINCT
    awb.ShipmentID, 
    awb.OrderID,
    awb.UserID,
    awb.Content,
    awb.TrackingID
FROM
    AWB
JOIN
    Orders o ON o.OrderID=awb.OrderID
WHERE
  o.Hold=0
```

I would expect that with this situation the select will NOT return Order 25

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: Can you add the expected result as well

Comment: Sure, just added, but simply not return Order 25 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this where clause:

```
where o.OrderID not in (select OrderID from Orders where Hold=1)
```

For speedup you can drop the join of orders and filter direct on awb.OrderID

```
where awb.OrderID not in (select OrderID from Orders where Hold=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding not exists in where clause -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    awb.ShipmentID, 
    awb.OrderID,
    awb.UserID,
    awb.Content,
    awb.TrackingID
FROM
    AWB
JOIN
    Orders o ON o.OrderID=awb.OrderID
WHERE
  o.Hold=0
  and not exists (select 1 from Orders od where od.OrderID = o.OrderID and od.Hold = 0 group by od.OrderID having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but does 'not exists' add some extra features? since the solution proposed by Bernd Ott is much simpler
Thanks for your time